# ValueQ returns false positive for one argument type only

Tags: argument-patterns, expression-test

I'm seeing some perplexing behavior from `ValueQ` in 10.3. Consider:

```
f[r_List, n_Integer] := r^n;
ValueQ[f[{}, 1]]

(* ==> True *)

ValueQ[f[{}, 0.3]]

(* ==> False *)

ValueQ[f[{}, \[Pi]]]

(* ==> False *)

ValueQ[f[{a, b, c}, 3/2]]

(* ==> True *) (* THIS IS UNEXPECTED *)

f[{1,2,3}, 3/2]

(* ==> f[{1,2,3}, 3/2] *)
```

What I expect is that any `ValueQ` call that has an argument list that matches the types in the function definition's pattern -- and therefore could be transformed by the rule associated with that definition -- will return `True`. Any call with an argument list having different types will return `False`. As I understand it, what `ValueQ` does is test whether a rule exists that would transform its argument.

And that's what happens, EXCEPT for the final case, in which a `{List,Rational}` slips through when only a `{List,Integer}` should. `ValueQ` returns `True`. And yet, if I actually evaluate that function with those arguments, no transformation occurs, because (of course) no appropriate rule exists.

It seems that `ValueQ` is simply failing. Is this a bug, or do I fail to understand some subtlety here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, the documentation of [`ValueQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ValueQ.html) states

> `ValueQ` gives `False` only if `expr` would not change if it were to be entered as Wolfram Language input.

This explains pretty much everything you are experiencing. Very easy example:

```
Hold[1/2]//FullForm
(* Hold[Times[1,Power[2,-1]]] *)
```

You see that you enter `1/2` as a multiplication but what if we don't hold it? See what happens:

```
1/2//FullForm
(* Rational[1,2] *)
```

The expression changes into something different. Therefore, you should be able to guess the answer of

```
ValueQ[1/2]
```

without evaluating it. And indeed, using the `PrintDefinitions[ValueQ]` function (I saw it in the `Trace`) from the `` <<GeneralUtilities` `` package in version 10 shows you that `ValueQ` for general expressions like yours does nothing more than

```
ValueQ[expr_] := !Hold[Evaluate[expr]] === Hold[expr];
```

So it compares the completely evaluated form of your `f[...]` call, with the held one. So even if your pattern does not match, as long as *anything* changes in the expression, the result will be `True`.

So one solution for you is simply, to prevent this behavior by evaluating the arguments of `f` *before* feeding it to `ValueQ`. I'm not completely sure about all consequences, but it seems in your situation this could be what you want:

```
SetAttributes[valueQ, {HoldFirst}];
valueQ[h_[args__]] := With[{eval = args},
  ValueQ @@ (HoldComplete[eval] /. Sequence :> h)
]

f[r_List, n_Integer] := r^n;
valueQ[f[{},1]]
valueQ[f[{},0.3]]
valueQ[f[{},π]]
valueQ[f[{a,b,c},3/2]]
(* True *)
(* False *)
(* False *)
(* False *)
```

A different, but similar way is to define your `valueQ` in the same manner as the real `ValueQ`:

```
valueQ2[h_[args___]] := With[{eval = args},
  ! Hold[Evaluate[h[args]]] === (Hold[eval] /. Hold[expr___] :> Hold[f[expr]])
]
```

Comment: Ah! :D In that case, the cure is something like `SetAttributes[f, HoldAll]`...

Comment: Aha! So I can instead use `ValueQ[f[{}, Rational[3,2]]]` instead of `ValueQ[f[{}, 3/2]]` to check whether `f[_List,_Rational]` has been defined! Thank you.