# Using ValueQ to test whether "hash" key exists fails when key is given as variable

Tags: expression-test, downvalues

**Please ignore ^^^ possible duplicate (raised by me). The solution doesn't cover my case.**

I'm trying to implement a simple hash table according to [this top answer at "Is there HashTable structure in Wolfram Mathematica?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1394326/925913)

That is, (copied from linked post)

```
(* Set some values in your table.*) 
table[a] = foo; table[b] = bar; table[c] = baz;

(* Test whether some keys are present. *)
{ValueQ[table[a]], ValueQ[table[d]]}
(* Out: {True, False} *)

(* Get a list of all keys and values, as delayed rules. *)
DownValues[table]
(* Out: {HoldPattern[table[a]] :> foo, HoldPattern[table[b]] :> bar, HoldPattern[table[c]] :> baz} *)

(* Remove a key from your table. *)
Unset[table[b]]; ValueQ[table[b]]
(* Out: False *)
```

Testing a key fails, however, when supplied from a variable, *e.g.*

```
table[a] = foo; table[b] = bar; table[c] = baz;
{ValueQ[table[a]], ValueQ[table[d]]}
(* Out: {True, False} *)

key = d; ValueQ[table[key]]
(* Out: True *)
```

[ValueQ's documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ValueQ.html) does state that it *"returns True if any evaluation takes place"*.

How should I test keys held in variables?

---

**EDIT**

I voted to close this question having found a possible duplicate, but after trying both of @halirutan's solutions, I'm sad to report that neither work for my case. @halirutan's test cases involved numerics, while mine involves a symbol with a `DownValue`. So, I am still in search of a solution. Currently I am trying to decipher @halirutan's solutions so I can figure out where things are going wrong.

Comment: But why not just use `Association`s?

Comment: :-( When I search `mathematica hash table` on Google, the link I posted is the first or second hit, and even doing some additional searches don't lead to `Association`. This is my first time hearing of it. I even searched sparse arrays.

Comment: Actually, I also see that `Association` was introduced in version 10. I have version 9, so I'd still appreciate an answer for my case.

Comment: I think your question is more fundamental than hash tables, it's really a question about how `ValueQ` works with respect to evaluation order. If you do `ValueQ[Evaluate[key]]` do you get the correct result? You should read up on `Attributes` specifically, `HoldAll`.

Comment: @N.J.Evans - You know, I actually tried that after I saw the `HoldAll` attribute, and sure, it appears to work, but I didn't have any confidence that it was actually working, since there's only two outcomes—True or False—and maybe some other effect was making it show the "correct" value. Please do post it as an answer if with your knowledge of how `ValueQ` works, `Evaluate` is a proper solution :-)

Comment: @N.J.Evans - Uh oh, nope. `Evaluate` does not work. It makes `ValueQ` always return `False`. I think I remember reading that `Evaluate` actually can't override a symbol's `HoldAll` attribute. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ValueQ returns false positive for one argument type only](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98674/valueq-returns-false-positive-for-one-argument-type-only)

Comment: I saw that as I was writing up an answer. Looks like halirutan covers it pretty well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### tl;dr

Use this modified `valueQ` function.

```
SetAttributes[valueQ, {HoldFirst}];
valueQ[h_[args__]] :=
    With[{eval = args},
       ! Hold[Evaluate[h[eval]]] === Hold[h[eval]]
    ];
```

---

#### How `ValueQ` works.

I learned from @halirutan's answer in [ValueQ returns false positive for one argument type only](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98674/valueq-returns-false-positive-for-one-argument-type-only) that `ValueQ` simply tests whether an expression is equal to running `Evaluate` on itself, *i.e.*

```
ValueQ[expr_] := !Hold[Evaluate[expr]] === Hold[expr];
```

If it *does* match up, then this non-transformation indicates non-value, and vice versa.

#### The issue with variables (DownValues).

So here's what was happening. Let's take @halirutan's example:

```
table[a] = foo;
table[b] = bar;
table[c] = baz;
{ValueQ[table[a]], ValueQ[table[d]]}

(* {True, False} *)
```

This is correct, of course—`a` is a key, `d` is not. Now, let's introduce `keyA` and `keyD`:

```
keyA = a;
keyD = d;
{ValueQ[table[keyA]], ValueQ[table[keyD]]}

(* {True, True} *)
```

Wait, but why? Well, let's plug in our expression into @halirutan's exposed `ValueQ` expression, *i.e.*

```
ValueQ[expr_] := !Hold[Evaluate[expr]] === Hold[expr];
```

For the `keyA` case, here are the evaluated and non-evaluated sides, separately:

```
{Hold[Evaluate[table[keyA]]], Hold[table[keyA]]}

(* {Hold[foo], Hold[table[keyA]]} *)
```

So, you see, `table[keyA]` is fully evaluated to `foo` on the LHS (as expected), while `table[keyA]` stays as is on the RHS (as expected), and the fact that they're different means `ValueQ` should return `True`, *i.e.* the expression indeed "has a value," transforming when evaluated.

Now, let's do the same for `keyD`:

```
{Hold[Evaluate[table[keyD]]], Hold[table[keyD]]}

(* {Hold[table[d]], Hold[table[keyD]]} *)
```

Here we see the issue. Even though `table[d]` doesn't have a value, the evaluation of `keyD` to `d` is still considered a transformation. Therefore when compared to the RHS, which has remained `table[keyD]`, the difference leads to `ValueQ` returning `True`.

#### Evaluating both sides.

This was the first thing I tried, *e.g.*

```
{ValueQ[Evaluate[table[a]]], ValueQ[Evaluate[table[d]]]}

(* {False, False} *)
```

But now that we know how `ValueQ` works, it becomes a silly solution. By `Evaluate`ing the expression prior to passing it into `ValueQ`, we guarantee that it *will* match during the comparison, since the very thing that `ValueQ` does is `Evaluate` the expression, making `ValueQ` return `False` always (*i.e.* the expression didn't transform, so it "has no value").

#### Finally, the solution.

@halirutan's two answers actually cover a more sophisticated problem than mine, but also different enough that neither cover the transformation of variables (*i.e.* symbols with `DownValue`s).

It was pretty easy to come up with a solution, however. We simply need the argument (the "key" expression) to be evaluated before being passed into `ValueQ`:

```
SetAttributes[valueQ, {HoldFirst}];
valueQ[h_[args__]] :=
    With[{eval = args},
       ! Hold[Evaluate[h[eval]]] === Hold[h[eval]]
    ];
```

This appears to work fine:

```
{valueQ[table[keyA]], valueQ[table[keyD]]}

(* {True, False} *)
```