# Bug with ValueQ involving fractions?

Tags: symbols, constraint

Expected behavior:

```
ClearAll[f];
ValueQ[f[1]]
```

`False`

Unexpected behavior:

```
ClearAll[f];
ValueQ[f[1/2]]
```

`False`

Fractions seem to ruin the behavior of `valueQ`. Is this a bug? What's going on here?

Comment: The `bugs` tag is reserved for questions where the problem has been vetted by this community and the observed behavior is confirmed to be a bug. Please do not use this tag for new questions.

Comment: @creidhne Oh sorry. Is there a proper tag for a suspected bug?

Comment: there’s no suspected bug tag. The title and your question tell everyone that you suspect a bug.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ValueQ returns false positive for one argument type only](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98674/valueq-returns-false-positive-for-one-argument-type-only)